# About the proof that $\mathbb{Z_{3}} \times \mathbb{Z_{3}}$ is not cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> [image]

I am not understanding why if every element added three times gives the identity won't generate the other elements of the group.

Comment: If every element is order 3, then the cyclic subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_{3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3}$ generated by any element has three elements. Hence, since $\mathbb{Z}_{3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3}$ has nine elements, no element generates $\mathbb{Z}_{3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3}$, i.e. it is not cyclic.

Comment: @AWertheim, oh okay. From the comment, I thought it was saying $Z_3$ isn't cyclic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a cyclic group of order $9$ there must be an element of order $9$ by definition of cyclic group.

But in $\mathbb{Z_{3}} \times \mathbb{Z_{3}}$ the order of each element is $1$ or $3$, because for every $(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z_{3}} \times \mathbb{Z_{3}}$ we have $$3\cdot (a,b) = (3a,3b) = (0,0) = 0_{\mathbb{Z_{3}} \times \mathbb{Z_{3}}}$$

So $\mathbb{Z_{3}} \times \mathbb{Z_{3}}$ isn't cyclic.

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to say that a group generated by an element has at most cardinality 3, so it is not the whole group, which has cardinality 9. Therefore the group can't be cyclic.